# Why are my clip-path scale animations blurry?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on a website with a full-screen loading screen where, once everything in the site is loaded, the box in the middle (which has an SVG `clip-path` in it) would increase in size in an intentionally jerky manner until it fills up the whole screen.

However, I'm trying to figure out why the box looks blurry while animating. I've tried doing all GPU acceleration methods including `transform: translateZ(0)`, `backface-visibility` and `perspective`, but to no avail.

```css
#loading {position:fixed; width:100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content:center; background: #34d1bf;}
#loading .bar {width: 169px; height: 160px; clip-path: url(#kframe); -webkit-clip-path: url(#kframe); background:#000; overflow: hidden; transform: translateZ(0); animation: loaded 2000ms linear forwards infinite;}

@keyframes loaded {
    0% {transform: scale(1);}
    1% {transform: scale(1);}
    
    32% {transform: scale(1);}
    33% {transform: scale(5);}
    
    65% {transform: scale(5);}
    66% {transform: scale(10);}
    
    99% {transform: scale(10);}
    100% {transform: scale(15);}
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
<div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<div style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="kframe" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon transform="scale(0.00390 0.00390)" points="256,0 0,0 0,72 18,72 18,184 0,184 0,256 222.5,256 256,220 256,36 222.5,36 "/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
</div>
```

Update: Here's a photo of one frame where the blur is most evident, as tested on the local version that's on my computer. Upon testing, it happens more on Chrome and Safari.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see and/or understand what you meant by the blurry box when animating. Could you show us a picture and highlight the blurry area?

Comment: @Richard Updated with screenshot. Apparently, the simulation I coded above ran faster than the similar original version that's on my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is clipping the div element and then scaling it.

Instead, do it the other way around. Scale the div and then clip it.  One way to do that it animate the div's width and height.

```css
#loading {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  background: #34d1bf;
}

#loading .bar {
  width: 169px;
  height: 160px;
  clip-path: url(#kframe);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#kframe);
  background:#000;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  animation: loaded 2000ms linear forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes loaded {
    0% {width: 169px; height: 160px;}
    1% {width: 169px; height: 160px;}
    
    32% {width: 169px; height: 160px;}
    33% {width: 845px; height: 800px;}
    
    65% {width: 845px; height: 800px;}
    66% {width: 1690px; height: 1600px;}
    
    99% {width: 1690px; height: 1600px;}
    100% {width: 2535px; height: 2400px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
<div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<div style="height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="kframe" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <polygon transform="scale(0.00390 0.00390)" points="256,0 0,0 0,72 18,72 18,184 0,184 0,256 222.5,256 256,220 256,36 222.5,36 "/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Decided to give the box a percentage width with a percentage bottom padding to maintain aspect ratio instead, and everything looks as it should. However, I now need to find a way for the box's width and height to be able to go beyond the parent `#loading` element's full width and height bounds.

Comment: Adding `overflow:visible` to the parent shpould achieve that.  You may also need to add it to higher ancestors also if they tightly wrap the parent.